# How can I secure my spindles?

Tags: wood, stairs, handrail

My house has 3 stories, and from the first floor to the second it has spindles.

My issue with them is that they seem very rickety, and don't support any weight what so ever.

Is it possible to secure them?

[image]
The top set seem to be much worse than the bottom.

Comment: The hand rail feels rickety, or the spindles can move around?

Comment: The entire thing shakes with little to no effort.

Comment: Are the newel posts wobbly, or does it feel like the handrail is not connected well to the newel posts?

Comment: The entire thing feels quite loose. How do I identify the newel?

Comment: The newel post, is the vertical post that the handrail attaches to. In your photo, it's the vertical (4×4) post in the left-center of the photo. The one with the large knob on top.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm not at the house anymore but I'll see if that one is loose too.

Comment: The balusters (spindles) don't do much to add structure to the railing, other than keeping the handrail a fixed distance from the bottom rail. In fact, they typically sit in the plow of the handrail and bottom rail, and are only held in place by pieces of fillet. They offer little to no lateral support.

Comment: So the spindles between the newels are mostly for show?

Comment: If the railing is wobbling, it's not likely a problem with the balusters.  Either the newel is damaged or loose, or the handrail is not firmly attached to the newel.

Comment: The balusters hinder you from slipping under the handrail.

Comment: Have you made any progress determining what's loose?

Answer (score 3):

Stair hand rails are primarily supported at the top and bottom by the newel posts. While some additional support is needed in a span over 5 or 6 feet, the handrail does not need dozens of braces. You will often see an inside wall handrail with attachments that are several feet apart. The spindles are primarily intended for safety, to prevent someone from slipping under the handrail on an open staircase.

No spindles on a full handrail run would allow the rail to flex too much, so they are necessary. But if a number of them are loose, there is little likelihood of risk unless the attachment at the newels is also compromised.

Having said that, it makes sense to firm up the spindles. Driving 1 1/2 or 2" finish nails on an angle, pinning the tops and bottoms of the spindles to the handrail and the base should probably do it (much easier with a nailgun).

Answer (score 1):

I know many times the spindles are only toe nailed in place. If this is the case you could pull the nails and use wood glue and screws. Make sure if you use screws to pre-drill the spindles or they will split.

Comment: By toe nailed do you mean like small tacks?

Comment: Small finishing nails a very small head or a wire brad shot from a small [nail gun](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Porter-Cable-18-Gauge-Pneumatic-Brad-Nailer-Kit-BN200C/203555573)

Comment: I sense some might not understand the concept of toe-nailing.  It is driving a nail down at a 45 or higher angle through the post and into the tread.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to get a Carpenter or even a Stair Builder to fix your problems once & permanently. You can try the underside of the handrails for the solutions here 
[**How do I tighten/loosen this recessed nut and bolt?**](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/38323/how-do-i-tighten-loosen-this-recessed-nut-and-bolt) But, that will only fix the loose handrails & **maybe** the spindles.

If the Newel Posts at the ends of the handrails are loose, you might be able to drill-out round plugs to re-tighten them, the same as the underside of the handrails (if you had that). Otherwise, [**you might have to do something like this.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6_TNkcGL5I)